# Joomla Editor form action target="_blank" truncated issue

Tags: joomla, tinymce, joomla2.5, joomla1.5

While i was inserting a form into an article in Joomla, i had to place the forms target attribute as target="_blank" so that when the user submits the form, the form submits to a new page.

But as per Joomla's default configuration everything including form's markup went into the article html data except for the attribute target="_blank".

The editor used during the issue was Tinymce.

I'm trying to fix this  issue without having to edit the source code in javascript or php.
I'm hoping for a quick fix from the Joomla's configuration somewhere.

Comment: Going to look into plugin configurations now.

Comment: Are you sure adding a form to the article is the best idea? Please consider using a form extension from the Joomla Extensions Directory. It will most likely solve your problem. TinyMCE is extremely annoying when it comes to filtering.

Comment: Thanks @Lodder yes tinymce has annoyed me a lot, but it sure is a great extension. The specific issue i had was to show a form element right in between an article content of mine. I'm getting some headsup on this. It sure has to deal with Tinymce's Extend valid elements scheme [link]http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/configuration:extended_valid_elements

Comment: hmm. If you let me know what fields you have on the forum, I could help you find a form module, which you could then easily place inside your article using `{loadposition xxxxxx}`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the support.
Finally I got it figured out, without even having to change one single line of source code.
The issue was indeed by the extended valid elements options of the tinymce editor to be used.

But in Joomla, the tinymce plugin does allow to handle it from the plugin backend.

Goto Joomla plugin manager => Editor- TinyMce

Under the right Plugin configuration options, you can see at the bottom the configuration option:
**Extended Valid Elements**
There you can add the values
`form[action|accept|accept-charset|enctype|method|target]` & click save/apply.

Add the target="_blank" anywhere in your article html code & it will not be trucated anymore 
:)

Cheers
I hope this helps someone who stumbled on this issue.